# Create an XML file from a text file

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have a text file like that contains contact information like this:

```
martin@actionbase.se, Martin Grape, HTML
pedram@actionbase.se, Pedram Mebedi, HTML
```

I need to convert the above information into proper XML form like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Subscribers>
    <Subscriber>
        <Name>Martin Grape</Name>
        <Email>martin@actionbase.se</Email>
        <Format>HTML</Format>
    </Subscriber>
    <Subscriber>
        <Name>Pedram Mebedi</Name>
        <Email>pedram@actionbase.se</Email>
        <Format>HTML</Format>
    </Subscriber>
</Subscribers>
```

And I need to do this pragmatically. So do I have to come up with my own algorithm or is there a faster way to this? Thanks.

Comment: there are several tools like [csv2xml](http://csv2xml.sourceforge.net/), but you will write your own converter in less time than searching for and configuring something already done..

Comment: Yes but I need to do this in VB.Net code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inspiration in C#, you can easily convert to VB.NET and extend:

```
var xml = new StringBuilder();

xml.Append("<Subscribers>");

foreach(var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"yourfile.txt"))
{
    var vals = line.Split(',');

    // TODO add more fields
    xml.AppendFormat("<Subscriber><Name>{0}</Name><Email>{1}</Email></Subscriber>",
        vals[0].Trim(), vals[1].Trim());

}

xml.Append("</Subscribers>");

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"your.xml", xml.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which platform you are using and I can't speak for all but I think you'll need to come up with your own code to convert this into XML. Should be pretty simple though as you can just read each line and split it on the comma to get each item of data.

Comment: Wow I think that's just the tutorial I needed. Need to spend time on it though.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use different tools like [SoftSilver](http://www.softsilver.com/).

YOu can check out this link. It will surely help you:- http://www.devx.com/getHelpOn/10MinuteSolution/20356